# bookkeeping cleanup of equivalent changes across branches in git

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I'm attempting to cleanup a large number of topic branches, primarily so that the branch overview for `master` in github no longer displays spurious "n ahead" indicators in inactive topic branches due to the presence of identical changes.

Without these spurious indicators, this overview page would offer a great way to see at a glance if any commits from old topic branches were inadvertently missed and not merged back down into `master`.

In the diagram below, `Y` is a commit in branch `topic` that was later applied to `master` as `Y'` (so they have different sha1 hashes, but identical patch ids).

```
A --- B --- C --- Y' --- E    <-- master
       \ 
        X --- Y               <-- topic
```

`git cherry master topic` appropriately reports:

```
- Y
```

But if I try to clean this up by issuing a `git merge topic` from `master`, I get a merge conflict since change `E` in `master` has since altered the context against which the patch applied.

Is there a way to tell `master` "Hey, you really do have `Y` already, so you can stop reporting that you don't."? (Being able to do this in such a way that it could be applied automatically/programmatically is key.)

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but does X also exist in master? Or is it only in topic?

Comment: Maybe you can amend your Y commit in the topic branch to your Y commit in master? Hmmm not sure... just thinking out loud. Seems like you need a way to say Y in topic is Y in master...

Comment: In most cases it isn't relevant whether `X` is in `master`. When it isn't, it is almost always a changelist that affects files orthogonal to `Y` and `Y'`.

Comment: All of these commits are published, so I don't want to do anything that rewrites history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why I didn't think of this before, but as long as an identical changelist is the only difference between `master` and `topic`, `git merge -s ours topic` from `master` will easily solve the problem. The merge will obviously apply without conflict, and the presence of the merge will eliminate the spurious unmerged indicator.

My github branch overview page is now free of misleading "n ahead" indicators, so genuine unmerged commits will stick out clearly.

Comment: `git merge -s recursive -Xours topic` may be a better merge command for this in the general case—if there are additional commits to merge as well—since it favors `master` but doesn't entirely discard `topic` .

Answer (score 1):

You can see the effective difference in revisions between branches by passing the --cherry-pick option to git log.

My favourite incantation runs:

```
git log --left-right --graph --cherry-pick --oneline branch1...branch2
```

(which I have *aliases* as `git lr`).

From [the man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> ```
> --cherry-pick
> ```
>
> *Omit any commit that introduces the same change as another commit on the "other side" when the set of commits are limited with symmetric difference*.
>
> For example, if you have two branches, A and B, a usual way to list all commits on only one side of them is with `--left-right` (see the example below in the description of the `--left-right` option). It however shows the commits that were cherry-picked from the other branch (for example, "3rd on b" may be cherry-picked from branch A). **With this option, such pairs of commits are excluded from the output**.
>
> ```
> --cherry-mark
> ```
>
> Like `--cherry-pick` (see <strike>below</strike>*above*) but mark equivalent commits with `=` rather than omitting them, and inequivalent ones with `+`.

---

#### Permanent solution #1

In order to permanently make git stop worrying about commits that were actually cherry-picked, you can always *merge* the other branh. The merge commit will be marked as **a child revision** of both the previous commit **and the tip of the merged revision tree**.

This tells the revision tree traversal to stop walking the history at that point. Doing so would only be safe when merging a revision from the 'other' branch IFF you **know that all it's parents *have been merged* (as far as you would ever want them merged).

#### Permanent solution #2

There is also some [way to use *grafts*](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint). This really means nothing more than that you'll tell git - out of band[1](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) - that a certain revision is a child of another revision, without having to actually rebase onto/merge from it.

<sub>[1](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) as in, a handwritten file with pairs of sha1 hashes :)</sub>

The positive thing about this is that you *don't **have** to rewrite history* for this to work. However, if you want to, you can use [`git filter-branch` to make the grafts permanent](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch). You no longer need the *grafts* file then, but of course, you'll be back with the disadvantages of having to rewrite the history (and possibly invalidating published revision ids).

#### Loose ends?

If all else fails, sometimes you can be stuck with remote (topic) branches that you frequently want to merge from, but there are differences that you simply never want to take. These would probably result in the same merge conflicts over and over.

In that case I'll just point at [git-rerere (Reuse recorded resolution of conflicted merges)](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html) which can make life considerably easier, albeit more complicated

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, solution #1 doesn't work because it is already an aspect of my problem. The merge isn't clean.

As for solution #2, I've never run across _grafts_ before. I'll look into that.

I know about cherry-pick, and I can craft a commandline to give me a report with only the unmerged changelists without equivalents in `master`. The problem is that the github overview page that my peers will be using won't use my custom commandline, so I need to actually eliminate the spurious indicators.

Comment: To rid spurious indicators, `rebase` is the way to go. You'll still have to resolve the conflicts manually, but hey... we all learn those things the hard way :)

Comment: This command did not show any cherry-picks, I ended up using `git cherry`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of an odd sidestep around not wanting to `rebase` history since this is a public repo, but consider a solution with `revert`, `merge`, and a counter `revert`.

On `master`, revert E and Y' separately to restore `master` to its state at C (with commit messages saying that you are bringing in a forgotten topic branch, not removing changes):

```
git revert E
git revert Y'
```

Note down the sha1 of the revert commit for E, or `git tag revert_E sha1` it.

Now you will be able to merge your `topic` onto `master`:

```
git merge topic
```

With topic properly merged at this point, and `master` returned to its state up to Y/Y', you can now `revert` your revert commit of E to restore it:

```
git revert revert_E
```

which will apply cleanly since `master` is in the same state it was when you originally committed E (the history to that state has just changed). Feels a bit acrobatic, but would solve your problem. I can't think of anything cleaner.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. Unfortunately, in practice there are usually many more commits than `E` between `Y'` and `HEAD`, so reverting `n` commits and then reapplying them is impractical and the resulting history would likely be confusing to other developers on the project.